# Uploading an Image to Twitter Using OAuth2 Results in 403 Error

Tags: java, kotlin, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to post a tweet with an image. I can successfully post a tweet with just text using OAuth2 authentication PKCE. However, when I try to upload an image, I get a 403 error code without any additional information.

I have tried both direct upload (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload) and with the INIT method (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-init).

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
fun uploadMediaToTwitter(accessToken: String, media: ByteArray) {
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val mediaBody = RequestBody.create("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(), media)

    val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("media", "image.png", mediaBody)
        .build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
        .post(requestBody)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .build()

    // Execute the request
    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        println("Result : code=${response.code}\nmessage=${response.message}\nbody=${response.body.string()}")
    }
}
```

Result : code=403
message=
body=

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!